# Is this hadith about a tree taking shahada miracle by Muhammad (saw) authentic?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation

I want to know if this hadith is authetnic, about a tree taking shahada by the command of Muhammad (saw) by the grace of Allah swt?

> It was narrated by Muhammad Ibn Tarif, narrated by Muhammad Ibn Fadil, narrated by Abu Hayan, narrated by Atta, narrated by Ibn Umar who said, "We were with the prophet – may Allah’s prayer and peace be upon him – on a journey when we were approached by a Bedouin.
>
> When the prophet saw him he said to him, ‘To where are you heading?’ The Bedouin said, ‘To my family.’ The prophet asked, ‘Do you wish to have a good thing?’ The Bedouin asked, ‘What would that be?’ The prophet replied, ‘To bear witness that there is no god but Allah alone, who has no partners and that Muhammad is His servant and messenger.’
>
> The Bedouin asked, ‘And who will testify to what you say?’ The prophet answered, ‘This tree will.’ So the prophet called to the tree that was in a valley by the seashore and it came to him, crawling on the ground until it stood up right between his hands. So the prophet made the tree say the Shahada three times and then it returned to where it was planted before.
>
> The Bedouin then returned to his people and said, ‘If they follow me I will bring them (to Muhammad) otherwise I will return to him myself." (Sunan Al-Darimi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hadith is quoted not only in sunan [ad-Darimi](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=137&pid=63979&hid=16) on the authority of ibn 'Omar (May Allah be pleased with both of them) (with a sane narrator chain), but also in sahih ibn Hebban, whom qualified it as sahih (as quoted in [a book](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?hflag=1&bk_no=325&pid=154621) of ibn Hajjar, with a strong and sane narrator chain) and in an apparently shorter version in Jami' [at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/urn/734950). It is also narrated by at-Tabarni in his kabir and al-Bazzar in his musnad.

Al-Albani has qualified it as sahih.

The version of at-Tirmidhi has been qualified as sahih by al-Hakim and Sheikh Sho'aib al-Aranaoot according to [this fatwa](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=200439) in Arabic.

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Jazakallah khir brother! Thank you very much! May Allah reward you.

Comment: @Ali If you would have taken the [tour] and checked the [help] you would know that we accept answers here by up-voting them or choosing the accepted sign (or both) of course you are free to wait for other answers!